# Generator vsdx (visio) class diagram from xml file, Java

Tags: java, xml, visio

I have an xml file in which I have some classes definitions. I need to export it to a vsdx diagram. So simply put, I need a way to convert xml to vsdx in Java.

What libraries should I use, can it be done in source code? Thank you.

Comment: Will you run this on the desktop or as a service on a server? If desktop, can you provide each user with a Visio license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind the VSDX file format is an OpenXML file format. That means that, theoretically, anyone could produce a VSDX file without resorting to hacking the file format.

That said, it's probably not terribly easy to do it. Microsoft has an article with examples on their website:

**Manipulate the Visio file format programmatically**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/how-to-manipulate-the-visio-file-format-programmatically

I don't know how adaptable this is to Java, but it's worth a look!

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, there is only one library for Java that can write Visio diagrams without Visio (on a Linux server?) - the Aspose product... The libre office library (libvisio) can only read.